# Strange failure audit in 2003 R2 X64 SP2

Tags: windows-server-2003

our server is running 2003 R2 X64 SP2, we keep seeing this in clusters of around 4 rapid fire. Sometimes 2 hours, sometimes around 8 hours apart with slight variations. I am also seeing the same blank username and domain in an account locked out message, I have tried disabling all scheduled tasks, if anyone has any idea please let me know! I find these processes running out of svc host:

AeLookupSvc, AppMgmt, BITS, Browser, CryptSvc, dmserver, EventSystem, helpsvc, IAS, lanmanserver, lanmanworkstation, Netman, Nla, RasMan, Schedule, seclogon, SENS, SharedAccess, ShellHWDetection, winmgmt, wuauserv, WZCSVC

Logon Failure:
    Reason:     Account currently disabled

    User Name:

   Domain:

 
    Logon Type: 3

 
    Logon Process:  Authz

 
    Authentication Package: Kerberos

 
    Workstation Name:   PPCLUBES_TS

 
    Caller User Name:   PPCLUBES_TS$

 
    Caller Domain:  PPCLUBES

 
    Caller Logon ID:    (0x0,0x3E7)

 
    Caller Process ID:  928

 
    Transited Services: -

 
    Source Network Address: -

 
    Source Port:    -

Comment: What is PPCLUBES_TS? the server that the event is being logged on?

Comment: yes that is the server we are logging with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can gather and assuming that PPCLUBES_TS is the name of the server that the message is being logged on if a service is attempting to log on with the built-in SYSTEM account.

Try the following:

1. **Stop the WMI Service**

   net stop winmgmt
2. **Wait to see if the Event recurs**

If this seems to solve the problem you can re-compile the SCM.mof

1. **From a cmd prompt enter the following (replace 00:00 with a time a few minutes from now):**

   at 00:00 /interactive cmd.exe
2. **When a new cmd prompt starts switch to it**
3. **Change directory to C:\Windows\System32\wbem**
4. **Execute the following comman**d

   mofcomp scm.mof
5. **Start/Restart the WMI service**

   net start winmgmt